# how to start Indesign CS5.5, opening a specific Template from java

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {

         // create a new array of 2 strings
         String[] cmdArray = new String[2];

         // first argument is the program we want to open
         cmdArray[0] = "C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe InDesign CS5.5/InDesign.exe";

         // second argument is a txt file we want to open with notepad
         cmdArray[1] = "Fiction-Meridian-No-Header-B-Standard.indt";

         // print a message
         System.out.println("Executing notepad.exe and opening example.txt");

         // create a process and execute cmdArray and currect environment
         Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray,null);

         // print another message
         System.out.println("example.txt should now open.");

      } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
}
```

Open the Indesign.exe works fine; but i want separte template file is not open...

This template file open normally window first come to font missing dialogue box
how to skip this line...

Comment: I've removed all the unrelated tags, and the begging for help; SekDinesh, I still don't understand what you're asking. Would you please edit your question, and try to put in words as simple as possible what you want to achieve. Is this question related to Java at all, or are you just asking how to call Indesign so that it opens a specific file?

Comment: yes...@Marcus Muller I need specific file open in java. But open that file normally first come to dialog box font missing and plugin whatever it is....how to skip this in java code

Comment: "font missing" sounds like a warning because ... A font is missing. So that's something broken with your document or your system (a font is missing!) so you *can't* fix this any way other than installing the missing font or modifying the document.

Comment: How do you think "dialog box font missing and plugin whatever it is" is going to help *anyone* help you? Please, at least try to offer the information anyone would need to solve this.

Comment: I need skip this dialog box....in java code. you know this code: `app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevels.neverInteract;` this is IndesignScript

Comment: It's not a solution -- the font is still missing. And since *you* know this, I wonder why you did not put it into your question. Again, you're relying on everyone else to a) read your mind, b) see your computer screen, c) solve your problem by ignoring it and d) repairing something broken without knowing what's broken about it.